# VBA code to create 2 graphs from overlapping, discontinuous arrays

Tags: excel, vba, scatter-plot, named-ranges

I am trying to automate a process to generate 2 XYScatter graphs from 1 table and seem to be making a mess of it. There are multiple issues I'm hitting so I will try to describe 1 at a time.

The first issue is setting the X & Y ranges. The table could contain anywhere from 4 to a few hundred rows. Column A = X values, column F says if it is level 1/graph 1 or level 2/graph 2, & column J = Y value. I created 4 Range variables, RngL1X, RngL1Y, RngL2X & RngL2Y. Then I wrote some code to loop through column F and fill the data ranges (see below).

1. What is the correct syntax to make an empty range? Before I can use them, the ranges need to have initial values. I would like to set them to "Empty" but VBA doesn't like any of the syntax I have tried: Set RngL1X = " ", RngL1X = IsNull, RngL1X = IsEmpty, etc.
2. Here's the loop code for filling the variables. I can't tell how well it will work until I solve the problem of the initial values.

   ```
   Range("F2").Select
   Do While IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = False
       If ActiveCell Like "*Level 1*" Then
           RngL1X = RngL1X & ", " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5)
           RngL1Y = RngL1Y & ", " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4)
       Else
           RngL2X = RngL2X & ", " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5)
           RngL2Y = RngL2Y & ", " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4)
       End If
       Debug.Print RngL2Y
       ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
   Loop
   ```

When I tested the loop with the variables as a string (not a range) it worked well.

Comment: `Range("A1:A2").ClearContents` clears a range. Note that you cannot make a range. Ranges exist only in worksheets and you can reference them but you cannot make one. So you need to reference one in a sheet and then you can clear it. • Can you please add example data to your question and show what you actually expect as result?

Comment: If the plots don't need to be dynamically-linked to the source cells then you can build arrays instead of ranges and assign those to the X/Y values for each plot